# MS Access query: Use a select statement within Switch() function

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am using switch() function for a conditional Update in MS Access query.  Below is my query

```
 UPDATE T_Generated_OpportunityLine SET PlContact_c = Switch(
 LowestlevelValue_c='PTFDS - FD ENCLOSURE SYSTEMS',Select OpportunityLine_PostCode.SESA from OpportunityLine_PostCode,T_Generated_OpportunityLine where OpportunityLine_PostCode.Postcode=T_Generated_OpportunityLine.Selected_Zip AND
 OpportunityLine_PostCode.OpptyLine_Ref='PTFDS',
 LowestlevelValue_c='DOOR ENTRY SYSTEM',Select OpportunityLine_PostCode.SESA from OpportunityLine_PostCode,T_Generated_OpportunityLine where  OpportunityLine_PostCode.Postcode=T_Generated_OpportunityLine.Selected_Zip AND
 OpportunityLine_PostCode.OpptyLine_Ref='Door Entry System'
);
```

I am aware with the syntax of switch() function:

```
Switch ( expression1, value1, expression2, value2, ... expression_n, value_n )
```

I have just made one modification i.e. instead of passing **Static** value for "**Value**" section **I am fetching this value Dynamically through Select Query**.

But when I am trying to execute the query Its stating an error message that:

```
The query must be an updatable query
```

I am sure that problem is for Select Statement inside Switch() function,but I need this conditional update on account of my project.

**Can anyone provide any suitable solution to this?  I also want to know can we pass dynamic value for "Value" Portion in Switch() syntax?**

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is your problem, but normally subqueries need to be enclosed in parentheses:

```
UPDATE T_Generated_OpportunityLine
     SET PlContact_c = Switch(LowestlevelValue_c='PTFDS - FD ENCLOSURE SYSTEMS',
                              (Select SESA
                               from OpportunityLine_PostCode
                                where OpportunityLine_PostCode.Postcode = T_Generated_OpportunityLine.Selected_Zip AND
                                      OpportunityLine_PostCode.OpptyLine_Ref = 'PTFDS'
                              ),
                              LowestlevelValue_c = 'DOOR ENTRY SYSTEM',
                              (Select SESA
                               from OpportunityLine_PostCode 
                               where OpportunityLine_PostCode.Postcode = T_Generated_OpportunityLine.Selected_Zip AND
                                     OpportunityLine_PostCode.OpptyLine_Ref='Door Entry System'
                              ));
```

However, I would write this with just one subquery:

```
UPDATE T_Generated_OpportunityLine
     SET PlContact_c = (Select SESA
                        from OpportunityLine_PostCode as pc
                        where pc.Postcode = T_Generated_OpportunityLine.Selected_Zip AND
                              (T_Generated_OpportunityLine.LowestlevelValue_c = 'PTFDS - FD ENCLOSURE SYSTEMS' AND pc.OpptyLine_Ref = 'PTFDS' OR
                               T_Generated_OpportunityLine.LowestlevelValue_c = 'DOOR ENTRY SYSTEM' AND op.OpptyLine_Ref='Door Entry System'
                              )
                        );
```

Comment: have you tested your subquery?@Gordon Linoff.When I tried your subquery in access it reported me **Syntax Error in query Expression**.Moreover your first solution of putting **()** in subquery didn't serve my purpose its reported the same error message as I mentioned in the question.

Comment: Is `T_Generated_OpportunityLine` a view or a table?  Do you have rights to update it?